Setting phone to silent automatically for certain period of the day
I want to silence my phone during bedtime, especially all chat notifications. In the settings menu (swipe down on the right side of the screen) there is an icon "bedtime mode" in my phone that may solve my problem. It can be triggered by schedule, by charging, or manually. I want to use the schedule trigger, but this is the start of my yak shaving journey:

Looks like the start and stop time is tied to the Clock app's Bedtime schedule. OK fine I'll adjust the stop time using the Clock app's bedtime feature.
But setting the stop time means Clock app will set up alarm to ring at the stop time! I don't want the alarm to ring at 4:00am, I just want the DoNotDisturb to end at 4:00am.
I worked around the issue by not selecting any sound for the alarm.
This kinda work but every morning I get notification that I haven't selected sound for my alarm.

Did I do this correctly? Is there a better way to silence my phone at certain time of the day?
Mobile phone is Redmi Note 10 Pro using Android 13.

You can extend the solution here to include all those apps which send notifications

I don't know for Redmi Note, but instead of using Bedtime Mode, have you checked whether there's a separate schedule in the Do Not Disturb settings itself?

You can set schedules in the Do Not Disturb settings.
Adding a schedule allows you to select days of the weeks as well as the timeframe on these days.
You can also allow certain things to still play sound while this is on, such as your alarm (Located on the alarms and Sounds menu in the DND settings)

Yes, but as the OP states, when the DND period ends the alarm goes off.  This has rendered Do Not Disturb effectively useless and is why a different solution is sought.
